# Does TreeGrid support objects without parent/child relationships?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin14

I'm trying to write an application that will present trees of "tasks", using the Vaadin `TreeGrid`.

A very important thing to note is that the tree node type contains no references to a parent or to any children. Instead, a separate type contains parent/child relationships, referencing the unique ID of items of the tree node type.

These two types are stored separately in their own database tables. The data itself was extracted from MS Excel files (don't ask why) and inserted into a database, which the application utilizes to access the data.

To present this more visually:

TaskMaster (the tree node type):

```
@Entity
public class TaskMaster extends AbstractEntity {

  private String   internalTaskID;
  private String   name;
  private TaskType type;
  // other fields

  ...
}
```

TaskRelationship (the parent/child relationships):

```
@Entity
public class TaskRelationship extends AbstractEntity {

  private String  taskView;
  private String  parentTaskID;
  private String  childTaskID;
  // other fields

  ...
}
```

I have written `@Repository` and `@Service` classes to facilitate retrieving the information as needed.

I cannot figure out how to get the grid to load and display the hierarchy of nodes that represent a task tree. I have looked at Vaadin examples and I have created a data provider to try to get this data loaded, to no avail. It loads only the root node and nothing else.

I am wondering if the tree grid only knows how to handle the hierarchy relationship when the node object contains references to parents and children. *My objects do not do this.* Instead, I have tried to set up logic in the service and data provider classes to "get" what is needed. Apparently that does not work. Either that or I'm missing something really subtle.

Here is some of the code that represents my efforts.

TaskMasterDataProvider:

```
public class TaskMasterDataProvider
    extends AbstractBackEndHierarchicalDataProvider<TaskMaster, Void> {

  ...

  @Override
  public int getChildCount(HierarchicalQuery<TaskMaster, Void> query) {
    logger.info("parent: {}", query.getParent());

    if (query.getParent() != null) {
      int count = service.getChildCount(query.getParent());
      logger.info("child count: {}", count);
    }

    return service.getChildCount(query.getParent());
  }

  @Override
  public boolean hasChildren(TaskMaster item) {
    logger.info("item: {}", item);
    return service.hasChildren(item);
  }

  @Override
  protected Stream<TaskMaster> fetchChildrenFromBackEnd(HierarchicalQuery<TaskMaster, Void> query) {
    logger.info("parent: {}", query.getParent());
    return service.getChildren(query.getParent()).stream();
  }

}
```

TaskMasterService:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class TaskMasterService {

  ...
    
  public List<TaskMaster> getTopLevelTasks() {
    List<TaskMaster> result = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> topLevelIDs = taskRelationService.getTopLevelParentTaskIDs();

    topLevelIDs.forEach(id -> {
      TaskMaster task = taskMasterRepo.findByInternalTaskID(id);

      if (task != null) {
        result.add(task);
      }
    });

    return result;
  }

  public int getChildCount(TaskMaster parent) {
    logger.info("parent: {}", parent);
    return parent != null
        ? taskRelationService.getChildRelationsForParent(parent.getInternalTaskID()).size()
        : 0;
  }

  public boolean hasChildren(TaskMaster parent) {
    logger.info("parent: {}", parent);
    return parent != null
        ? !taskRelationService.getChildRelationsForParent(parent.getInternalTaskID()).isEmpty()
        : false;
  }

  public List<TaskMaster> getChildren(TaskMaster parent) {
    logger.info("parent: {}", parent);
    List<TaskMaster> result = new ArrayList<>();

    if (parent != null) {
      List<TaskRelationship> childRelations = taskRelationService
          .getChildRelationsForParent(parent.getInternalTaskID());

      childRelations.forEach(relation -> {
        result.add(taskMasterRepo.findByInternalTaskID(relation.getChildTaskID()));
      });
    }

    return result;
  }

}
```

TaskTreeView:

```
@Route("tree")
@CssImport("./styles/shared-styles.css")
public class TaskTreeView extends VerticalLayout {

  ...
  private TreeGrid<TaskMaster>   taskGrid;
  private TaskMasterDataProvider provider;

  private TaskMasterService      taskService;

  public TaskTreeView(TaskMasterService taskService) {
    this.taskService = taskService;

    setSizeFull();
    addClassName("task-tree-grid");

    configureView();
  }
    
  private void configureView() {
    taskGrid = new TreeGrid<>();
    taskGrid.addHierarchyColumn(TaskMaster::getName).setHeader("Name");
    taskGrid.addColumn(TaskMaster::getType).setHeader("Type");

    taskGrid.getColumns().forEach(col -> {
      col.setAutoWidth(true);
      col.setResizable(true);
    });

    provider = new TaskMasterDataProvider(taskService);
    taskGrid.setDataProvider(provider);

    taskGrid.asSingleSelect().addValueChangeListener(event -> {
      if (event.getValue() != null) {
        provider.refreshItem(event.getValue(), true);
      }
    });

    add(taskGrid);

    taskGrid.setItems(taskService.getTopLevelTasks());
  }
    
}
```

This is not everything, but I think it's the most important. I can add more if necessary.

If anyone has insights into whether my theory has any merit, or whether I'm doing something completely wrong, please let me know.

Comment: I’m confused. A `TreeGrid` is a grid with hierarchy. If you don’t have the hierarchy, why not use the regular grid?

Comment: In fact you have a parent/child relationship, how it's organized in the database is really a problem for the Vaadin TreeGrid.
I don't see any big issue in your code and should display the treegrid with the items. What is not working? Do you have the root items?

Comment: I agree it should, but it does not. Yes, the data results in several distinct trees, each with a root node. Ideally, I would prefer to display just one tree at a given time, but am settling for showing the entire list of trees for simplicity. When I load the list into the grid, only the root nodes show, nothing underneath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you set the data provider for the treeGrid twice
once here

> taskGrid.setDataProvider(provider);

another one here

> taskGrid.setItems(taskService.getTopLevelTasks());

I believe you should remove the setItems instruction and that the implementation for **fetchChildrenFromBackEnd** should be similar to

```
 @Override
 protected Stream<TaskMaster> fetchChildrenFromBackEnd(HierarchicalQuery<TaskMaster, 
     Void> query) {
     logger.info("parent: {}", query.getParent());
     if (null == query.getParent()) {
         return taskService.getTopLevelTasks().stream();
     }
     return service.getChildren(query.getParent()).stream();
 }
```

Comment: There was also a critical bit of logic missing from the provider getChildCount() method.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @tremendous7 for giving me the idea that led to a solution. In addition to the idea given, I was also missing a critical piece of logic from the data provider getChildCount() method:

```
  @Override
  public int getChildCount(HierarchicalQuery<TaskMaster, Void> query) {
    logger.info("parent: {}", query.getParent());
    int count = 0;

    if (query.getParent() == null) {
      count = service.getTopLevelTasks().size();
    } else {
      count = service.getChildCount(query.getParent());
    }

    logger.info("child count: {}", count);
    return count;
  }
```